# How to start the slaves of a Spring Batch application that uses partitioning?

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-integration

We are using Spring Batch partitioning to do parallel processing of multiple input files on two JVMs. There's one master and one slave running in one JVM, and there's another slave running on a different JVM.

Starting the master and slave on the first JVM is done by starting the Spring boot app passing the job name just like starting any other batch job.

We are starting the slave on the second JVM by starting the Spring boot app passing a dummyjob name. The slave doesn't have the job config, it only has the inbound flow for receiving the message, the stepExecutionRequestHandler, and the step code.

**Result:** All the slave beans are initialized successfully, the slave consumer receives the message, and kicks off the stepExecutionRequestHandler, which fails creating a connection to the DB without any error. If I add the job config to the slave and start the job passing the right job name, the problem does not happen, which makes me think that the problem may be related to not starting a real Spring Batch job, which's supposed to initialize some required resources. I did verify that the datasourceConfiguration and datasource beans were initialized, which is done as part of a separate module.

So I'm wondering if I'm starting the slaves the right way, or if there's a better way to start them.

Here's the configuration of the slave:

```
  /*
   * Configure inbound flow (requests coming from the master)
   */

  @Bean
  public StepExecutionRequestHandler stepExecutionRequestHandler() {
    StepExecutionRequestHandler stepExecutionRequestHandler = new StepExecutionRequestHandler();
    stepExecutionRequestHandler.setJobExplorer(jobExplorer);
    stepExecutionRequestHandler.setStepLocator(stepLocator());
    return stepExecutionRequestHandler;
  }

  @Bean
  public StepLocator stepLocator() {
    BeanFactoryStepLocator beanFactoryStepLocator = new BeanFactoryStepLocator();
    beanFactoryStepLocator.setBeanFactory(beanFactory);

    return beanFactoryStepLocator;
  }

 @Bean
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inboundRequests")
  public StepExecutionRequestHandler serviceActivator() throws Exception {
    return stepExecutionRequestHandler();
  }

  @Bean
  public MessageChannel inboundRequests() {
    return new DirectChannel();
  }

  @Bean
  public AmqpInboundChannelAdapter inbound(SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer,
                                           @Qualifier("inboundRequests") MessageChannel channel) {
    AmqpInboundChannelAdapter adapter = new AmqpInboundChannelAdapter(listenerContainer);
    adapter.setOutputChannel(channel);
    return adapter;
  }

  @Bean
  public SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container =
      new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames(this.requestQueue);
    container.setPrefetchCount(1);

    return container;
  }

combineReleaseJobNormalStep CODE ...
```

Here's the configuration of the master:

```
  @Bean
  public Job combineReleaseJob() throws Exception {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("CombineReleaseJob")
      .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
      .listener(resourceLoader)
      .listener(combineReleaseJobJobContextPreparer())
      .flow(combineReleaseJobCL31401())
      .from(combineReleaseJobCL31401()).on("N").to(combineReleaseJobNormalStepManager())
      .from(combineReleaseJobCL31401()).on("R").end()
      .from(combineReleaseJobNormalStepManager()).on("COMPLETED").to(combineReleaseJobAddressTableCheck())
      .from(combineReleaseJobNormalStepManager()).on("FAILED").fail()
      .end().build();
  }

  @Bean
  public Step combineReleaseJobNormalStepManager() throws Exception {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("combineReleaseJobNormalStep.Manager")
      .partitioner("combineReleaseJobNormalStep",partitioner())
      .partitionHandler(partitionHandler())
      .build();
  }


  @Bean
  public PartitionHandler partitionHandler() throws Exception {
    MessageChannelPartitionHandler partitionHandler = new MessageChannelPartitionHandler();

    partitionHandler.setStepName("combineReleaseJobNormalStep");
    partitionHandler.setGridSize(GRID_SIZE);
    partitionHandler.setMessagingOperations(messageTemplate());
    //partitionHandler.setPollInterval(5000l);
    partitionHandler.setJobExplorer(this.jobExplorer);

    partitionHandler.afterPropertiesSet();

    return partitionHandler;
  }

  @Bean
  public MessagingTemplate messageTemplate() {
    MessagingTemplate messagingTemplate = new MessagingTemplate(outboundRequests());

    messagingTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(60000000l);

    return messagingTemplate;
  }

  /*
   * Configure outbound flow (requests going to slaves)
   */
  @Bean
  public MessageChannel outboundRequests() {
    return new DirectChannel();
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow outboundFlow(AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate) {
    return IntegrationFlows
      .from(outboundRequests())
      .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(amqpTemplate).routingKey(this.requestQueue))
      .get();
  }
```

Comment: `We are starting the slave on the second JVM by starting the Spring boot app passing a dummyjob name`: why do you need to start the slave with a dummy job name? This is a sign that you do not need this parameter in the worker side.

Comment: You are right, we were using the same batch app which required the batch job name. When we run as a non-batch app, the slave works fine. see my answer below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I add the job config to the slave and start the job passing the right job name, the problem does not happen, which makes me think that the problem may be related to not starting a real Spring Batch job,

You don't need to run an entire Spring Batch job on the worker side. The job is usually started on the master side and only worker steps are needed on the worker side. Please refer to the [Remote partitioning](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html#remote-partitioning) section of the reference documentation.

> How to start the slaves of a Spring Batch application that uses partitioning?

Workers can be started as a regular Spring (boot) app where a `StepExecutionRequestHandler` (usually configured as a Spring Integration service activator) listens to incoming `StepExecutionRequest`s and executes the worker step (located with a `StepLocator`).

You can find a complete set of examples in the talk [High Performance Batch Processing](https://springoneplatform.io/2018/sessions/high-performance-batch-processing) which I co-presented with Michael at SpringOne 2018. The source code of the examples can be found here: https://github.com/mminella/scaling-demos/tree/sp1-2018

Answer (score 0):

We found out we were starting the slave as a batch job, since it was added originally to the same batch application as the master. The job name was a required parameter in the batch app and it had a lot of dependencies on Spring batch tools and jars, so somehow it was trying to start a batch job and since the job config does not exist, it would fail in the middle of processing and shut down all the beans and resources, causing the DB connection issue above. When we run the slave as a deamon or a regular spring boot app, it starts fine and executes the step to completion.

To avoid doing a lot of rework and remove all the batch dependencies from the app to make it run as a regular Spring boot app, we used this code to make it run as a deamon :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args)));
  }

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Joining thread, you can press Ctrl+C to shutdown application");
    Thread.currentThread().join();
  }

}

``
```